# Source code of books made with TeX/LaTeX to learn

Tags: open-source, latex, tex, typography

Some time ago, reading [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563036/what-is-elegant-code/575983#575983) I found a nice image and a pointer to a better book entitled "Thinking Forth". To my surprise, the LaTeX sources of the book were ready to download, with pearls like:

```
%% There's no bold typewriter in Computer Modern.
%% Emulate with printing several times, slightly moving

\newdimen\poormove
\poormove0.0666pt
\newcommand{\poorbf}[1]{%
\llap{\hbox to \poormove{#1\hss}}%
\raise\poormove\rlap{#1\hss}%
\lower\poormove\rlap{#1\hss}%
\rlap{\hbox to \poormove{\hss}\hbox{#1}}%
#1}

%\let\poorbf=\textbf
\renewcommand{\poorbf}[1]{{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmtt}\fontseries{b}\selectfont#1}}
```

in which it can simulate the bold stroking of a font that doesn't have it. Since reading that, I was unaware of `\llap` and such, but now I can use them to define boxes, etc.

So, my question is twofold:

1. Do you know of sites that show that relatively advanced use of TeX/LaTeX in terms of useful recipes, and
2. Do you know any books that offer their TeX/LaTeX source to inspect and learn (and that are worth doing so.)?

Comment: Stack overflow should support LaTeX as one of the syntax highlighting classes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two comprehensive reference guides/recipe books for TeX:

- [TeX by Topic](http://www.eijkhout.net/tbt/) by Victor Eijkhout
- [TeX for the Impatient](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/impatient) by Paul Abrahams, Kathryn Hargreaves, and Karl Berry

In both cases, the sources are also available.

As lindelof mentions, the TeXBook is also available, albeit in a form that prevents compilation (Knuth wished people to look at the source for inspiration but not to reproduce the book freely):

- [The TeXBook](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) by Donald Knuth

On the LaTeX side of things, resources a little more scarce from the programming point of view. The best free reference that I know of is

- [Formatting Information](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/beginlatex/) by Peter Flynn

Of course there's also

- [The Not So Short Guide to LaTeX](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/) by Tobias Oetiker

but that doesn't cover so much programming "stuff". The LaTeX sources themselves contain some useful nuggets, but the quality of the documentation ranges from excellent to non-existent in parts; this should be available in your distribution with `texdoc source2e`.

Other large LaTeX packages obviously have the source to their documentation available; a notable example is the memoir class:

- [The memoir class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) by Peter Wilson (`memman.tex` is the documentation)

---

I'm sure there are many more books with their source available; these are just the first ones that come to mind that happen to also be able TeX and/or LaTeX.

Answer (score 6):

Believe it or not, but the source code to the [TeXbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201134470) is actually freely downloadable:

[TeXbook source code package](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook)

Comment: Thanks, lindelof, nice link! I was aware of it, but it is somewhat tough to read, and I was thinking more in the lines of LaTeX instead of TeX.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'd recommend it (unless you've got a lot of time and caffeine to spare), but I learned a lot from just reading the latex.ltx file. I learned a lot not only about LaTeX but also of course about TeX. It's a heavy read though and I'd suggest reading a book about TeX first before diving into the latex.ltx file.

I wanted to know about how "optional" parameters actually worked and reading the latex.ltx file really helped me understand.

Answer (score 1):

Another book that would definitely fit part 2 of your question is [*LaTeX for Complete Novices*](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/) by [TeX.SX member Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot).

[This later question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230526/list-of-books-written-in-latex-with-the-source-available), posted on TeX.SX, is also relevant for part 2 and worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

I found this book by Allen B. Downey that looks really nice: [Computational Modeling and Complexity Science](http://www.greenteapress.com/compmod/).